# Running multiple Apache2 instances on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2

I have two different config files (server1.conf & server2.conf). I need to use each of them to spawn an instance of apache.

**/etc/init.d/apache2 start** does let me specify which config file apache uses, it defaults to apache2.conf.

**apache2ctl -f /etc/apache2/server1.conf -k start** works, but when I try to spawn another instance it says that the PID is already in use.

**apache2 -f /etc/apache2/server1.conf -k start** I get an error saying **apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}.**

*How can I fix this?*

---

AS an aside, I need to instances of Apache running because I'm using mod_rails/passenger with it at that will only support one SSL certificate (even if you specify many). Hence, 2 instances to 2 support 2 certs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mod_rails. Just out of curiosity, why can't you use different certs on different virtual hosts?

Comment: You just can't.  I've read it in the documentation.  It will only read and use the first cert specified for all vhosts.  They may have updated, but I haven't seen it in the docs.

mod_rails is the name of Phusion Passenger.  This short coming aside, its one of the best ways to server Ruby on Rails applications.

Answer (score 3):

Change the PidFile path in one of your configs, they're trying to use the same one.

`PidFile /var/run/server2.pid`

for example

Comment: Does this file require any contents or is just used a pointer or sorts?

Comment: The pid file is used by Apache to store its PID (process ID), so it is a pointer to the running Apache process. It will create it if needed and will write to it. Therefore, the path must be writable by the Apache process.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good guide here:

http://blog.datajelly.com/company/blog/46-multiple-apache-instances-in-ubuntu.html

Essentially, you need two separate httpd.conf files which define two separate `LockFile` and `PidFile` directives.

Comment: Changing LockFile is unnecessary according to Apache2 docs:

> The LockFile directive sets the path to the lockfile used when Apache is compiled with either USE_FCNTL_SERIALIZED_ACCEPT or USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZED_ACCEPT. ... **The PID of the main server process is automatically appended to the filename.**